inheritance in JSON: unresolved reference
The following asyncapi:
{
  "asyncapi": "2.5.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "kafka producer service",
    "version": "${version}",
    "contact": {
      "email": "firstname.secondname@company.com",
      "url": "https://someurl"
    }
  },
  "channels": {
    "accounts": {
      "subscribe": {
        "message": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/messages/AccountEvent"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/messages/EndEvent"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "DataRecord": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": false
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "type"
        ]
      },
      "AccountRecord": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/messages/DataRecord"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "accountNumber": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": false
              },
              "timestamp": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ZonedDateTime",
                "nullable": false
              }
            },
            "required": [
              "accountNumber",
              "timestamp"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "ZonedDateTime": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date-time",
        "nullable": false
      },
      "EndRecord": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/components/messages/DataRecord"
          },
          {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "groupSize": {
                "type": "integer",
                "nullable": false
               }
            },
            "required": [
              "groupSize"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "messages": {
      "AccountEvent": {
        "x-name-constant": "AccountEvent",
        "x-version-constant": "${version}",
        "payload": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "dataRecord": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AccountRecord"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "dataRecord"
          ]
        }
      },
      "EndEvent": {
        "x-name-constant": "EndEvent",
        "x-version-constant": "${version}",
        "payload": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "dataRecord": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EndRecord"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "dataRecord"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

cannot resolve the references to DataRecord.
That is, the lines containing the following:
"$ref": "#/components/messages/DataRecord"

... are marked red due to "unresolved reference".
The DataRecord component is supposed to be the "parent component" of the two components AccountRecord and EndRecord.
According to this blog post: https://jason-ge.medium.com/class-inheritance-and-polymorphism-in-json-schema-6fe74345d208
this should work. But it doesn't.
Why can the reference not be resolved?

I see components/schemas/DataRecord in your JSON, but not components/messages/DataRecord.
